# Dell PowerConnect 2724 VLAN frame type filtering issue?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, vlan, dell-openmanage, dell-powerconnect

The endless VLAN headaches (and questions), eh?

I *really* have no idea how to title this one, do not judge.

I'm currently configuring VLANs on a Dell PowerConnect 2724 switch. Currently, all ports except 5 use PVID 1, no ingress filtering, admit all frames. Port 5 uses PVID 2. Ports 1 and 4 are tagged VLAN 2, and because PVID, untagged VLAN 1.

Visual representation (brackets = untagged / PVID):

1: [1] 2 <-- gateway
2: [1]
3: [1]
4: [1] 2 <-- me
5:     [2] <-- other host

When I set port 5's "Frame Type" from `Admit All` to `Admit Tag Only`, then I (port 4) can send and receive packets from the gateway (port 1), but cannot receive any packets from any other machines on the network (port 5). I should be sending tagged as VLAN 2 packets anyways, so the description of `Admit Tag Only` should allow it?

Reference:

- `Admit All`: "Tagged and untagged packets are accepted by the interface."
- `Admit Tag Only`: "Only tagged packets are accepted by the interface."

I'm kinda confused here, partially because.. VLAN, and partially because Dell equipment apparently doesn't have meaningful help and manuals.

Answer (score 0):

I have 10 2724's that I worked with in the past. The web interface was horrible and after suffering for 4 years I dumped them. Funny thing is, I bought 6248 dells and the backend web interface was not any better.

But I remember having an issue with the vlan and default lan and ability to tag the default. I came across that here. https://askshank.com/dell-powerconnect-2724-and-vlan-trunk/ Technically it applies to trunking, but perhaps the vlan1 situation is what is throwing it off and the ability to tag.